# C++ Guess Number game crashing on other computers and infinite loop fix

Tags: c++

```
// Guess my number
// My first text based game
// Created by USDlades
// http://www.USDgamedev.zxq.net

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // seed the random number generator

    int guess;
    int secret = rand() % 100 + 1; // Generates a Random number between 1 and 100
    int tries =0;

    cout << "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100, Can you figure it out?\n";

    do 
    {
        cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 100: ";
        cin >> guess;
        cout << endl;
        tries++;

        if (guess > secret) 
        {
            cout << "Too High!\n\n ";
        }
        else if (guess < secret)
        {
            cout << "Too Low!\n\n ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Congrats! you figured out the magic number in " << 
                    tries << " tries!\n";
        }
    } while (guess != secret);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

My code runs fine on my computer but when a friend of mine tries to run it, The program crashes. Does this have to do with my coding? Also I found that when I enter a letter for a guess, my game goes into an infinite loop. How can I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: So... *how* does it crash? On what operating system? With what input?

Comment: When she opens it on Windows Vista Premium, It crashes, does not even load my game I do not think

Comment: And what is the message it shows on the screen when it crashes? (If you don't know that already, *find out*. It will probably lead directly to the solution to your problem.)

Comment: Was that game built with VC++? If so, does your friend have installed either VC++ or the redistributable?

Comment: @Etieene de Martel it was built with Visual Studio 2010 Express. and they do not have it installed on their computer.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill - It is telling her the program is not installing correctly and asking if she would like to reinstall it.

Comment: Huh. Cheers for Windows now giving completely useless error messages. I was hoping it would tell you that it was missing a DLL (the runtime libraries mentioned in Jim Brissom's answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "crash" is probably related to missing runtime libraries, which would result in an error message similar to

> The application failed to initialize
>   properly [...]

...requiring your friend to install the missing runtime libraries, e.g.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=a5c84275-3b97-4ab7-a40d-3802b2af5fc2&displaylang=en

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84

Choose the version that matches whatever version of Visual Studio you used to develop your application, as well as the target platform.

As for your application entering an infinite loop: after entering a letter, the input stream will be in an error state and thus unusable. Code similar to the following will prevent that:

```
#include <limits>
...
...
...
std::cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 100: ";
std::cin >> guess;
std::cin.clear(); 
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Basically, the code [clears](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the error bits and [removes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) any remaining input from the input buffer, leaving the stream in an usable state again.

Comment: I tried your code and it treats the letters as a guess instead of going into that infinite loop. Thank you Jim.